# How can i fetch datas positioned in list and send it to another api's query parameter?

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

i need to fetch a string data from an api (this data located in a list) and i need to send this data to another api as a query parameter. I dunno how to send this as query parameter because this data positioned in a list.

**For a better understating** : [in this api](https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1) there is a key named steamid i need to fetch this steam id each time and send those as a parameter to [this api](https://playerdb.co/api/player/steam/76561198078971744)

```dart
class GDCubit extends Cubit<GDState> {
  GDCubit({
    required this.steamService,
    required this.steamReviews,
  }) : super(GDInitial()) {
    emit(GDInitial());
  }
  final SteamService steamService;
  final SteamReviews steamReviews;

  late final steamdata;
  late final steamreview;
  late final player;

  late String appId = '2208920';
  late String userId = '76561198078971744';

  late String? id = steamReviews.reviews![0].author?.steamid; // I tried to send first users steam id but cannot initialize

  void getDatas() async {
    try {
      emit(GDLoading());
      steamdata = await steamService.fetchRelatedAppWithId(appId);
      steamreview = await steamService.fetchSteamReviewsRelatedAppId(appId);
      player = await steamService.fetchPlayerInfo(id);
     //player = await steamService.fetchPlayerInfo(userId); //works properly but manually
      emit(GDLoaded(steamdata, steamreview, player));
    } catch (e) {
      return print('${e.toString()}' 'Error');
    }
  }
}
```

`

I tried to send steamid of first user in list but cannot initialize it

---

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to initialize the variable id before steamReviews, try creating the id inside your getDatas method, like this:

```
class GDCubit extends Cubit<GDState> {
  GDCubit({
    required this.steamService,
    required this.steamReviews,
  }) : super(GDInitial()) {
    emit(GDInitial());
  }
  final SteamService steamService;
  final SteamReviews steamReviews;

  late final steamdata;
  late final steamreview;
  late final player;

  late String appId = '2208920';
  late String userId = '76561198078971744';

  void getDatas() async {
    try {
      emit(GDLoading());
      steamdata = await steamService.fetchRelatedAppWithId(appId);
      steamreview = await steamService.fetchSteamReviewsRelatedAppId(appId);
      final id = steamReviews.reviews![0].author?.steamid; // Create id here 
      player = await steamService.fetchPlayerInfo(id);
      emit(GDLoaded(steamdata, steamreview, player));
    } catch (e) {
      return print('${e.toString()}' 'Error');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, data still comes null.

Comment: Can you verify if the data is mounted correctly inside fetchSteamReviewsRelatedAppId method?

Comment: got that, i accidentally used class name steamReviews i changed it to steamreview now data comes with no problem. I am showing this on listview and just seeing informations of first index is there any way to use this index properly ? Maybe i can use a button and increment index each time to show next review with correct index of user, i dunno. If it is possible to do that without button it would be better.

Comment: You have to create a logic to make this, is returned the first index cause you are using steamReviews.reviews![0], insert a dynamic index to get one by one